# how to solve a connection closed error in sql and python app

Tags: sqlite

import records

db = records.Database('sqlite:///database.db')

def create_tables(filepath):

```
content = ''

with open(filepath, 'r') as fl:
    content = fl.read()

    with db.transaction() as ass:
        

        ass = db.query(content)
```

i tried everything nothing works I just want to make it work